# Node.JS nonstop syntax errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting syntax errors when I attempt to run a discord bot on my VPS. I have all the required things installed on the VPS...

```
/root/node_modules/random.js:12 client.on('ready', () => {
                                                    ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const request = require('superagent');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client({ fetch_all_members: false,    
api_request_method: 'sequential' });


client.login(***);

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('ready!');
});

client.on('channelCreate', channel => {
console.log('made ${channel.name}');
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (g, m) => {
  console.log('${m.user.username} joined ${g.name}');
})

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (g, o, n) => {
  console.log(o.nickname, n.nickname);
});

client.on('debug', console.log);
```

I'm using Node version v0.10.46.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an old version of Node that does not support some of your ES6 syntax.

Comment: Information on which Node versions support arrow functions can be found here: http://node.green/#arrow-functions

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I have v0.10.46.....

Answer (score 1):

You are using a legacy branch of Node which uses a much older version of V8, so support for new ES6 syntax is limited.

From the [release versions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) page:

> - Version: Node.js v0.10.46
> - Date: 2016-06-23
> - V8: 3.14.5.9
> - npm: 2.15.1
> - NODE_MODULE_VERSION: 11

We can see this version of Node uses V8 version `3.14.5.9`. Contrast this with v6.7.0 which uses V8 `5.1.281.83`:

> - Version: Node.js v6.7.0
> - Date: 2016-09-27
> - V8: 5.1.281.83
> - npm: 3.10.3
> - NODE_MODULE_VERSION: 48

Possible solutions include using a newer branch of Node, or running you code through a transpiler first.